# Trigger a BSOD on Windows IoT Core device

Tags: powershell, uwp, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10, blue-screen-of-death

I am looking for a way to trigger *Blue Screen of Death* (BSOD) on an IoT Device running Windows 10 IoT Core version.

I tried doing some googling around, but any of the guides either do not apply to Windows 10 IoT Core (e.g. forcing it through Ctrl + 2x Scroll Lock key combination), or do not work at all (like killing *csrss.exe* process, which returns with "Access denied" error - doesn't matter if it is killed from IoT Core builtin Shell, or remote PowerShell session).

I also know about Microsoft's tool called *Not my fault*, but it's an **.exe** file, not an UWP **.appx** package that I could easily run on Windows 10 IoT Core system.

Best thing I can think of is some kind of remote PowerShell command or creating an app that could be triggered somehow to produce a *BSOD*.

**Disclaimer:** This is intended only for academic purposes, I do not want a "hacky" solution. The device I intend to trigger BSOD on belongs to me and I do **not** intend to use the methods provided to cause any mayhem to anyone else.

---

Edit: As suggested by @Sunius in comments, there is also a possibility of writing my own `kernel mode driver`. If I were to pursue this solution, how can I trigger a BSOD on demand with such a driver? I have no prior experience with writing Windows drivers, so any general tips on achieving this may be useful.

I understand the bit about dereferencing a null pointer, but as I understand it, this would normally happen on driver installation/load, and I would rather need a way to install/load the driver first, then, when necessary, trigger the BSOD using the driver I provided. What are the options to communicate with driver? Do drivers allow to trigger any action from say C# UWP Application (since I cannot run other apps on IoT Core OS)?

Are there any guides, references I could read? The Microsoft documentation on this topic is rather scarce and not beginner friendly (I suppose writing drivers shouldn't be done by begginers, but still).

Comment: Write a kernel mode driver and dereference a null pointer?

Comment: @Bart GSOD is only for Windows Insiders. Production builds still throw good old BSOD since GSOD is intended only to easily distinguish between Insider and production builds.

Comment: @Sunius I have also thought of the possibility of writing a driver that would trigger a BSOD, however I lack any experience with it. By `kernel mode driver` do you mean `KMDF`? I came by this abbreviaton reading MS docs, but I have never done driver programming and I'm pretty sure it isn't as straightforward as developing applications. Also - how can I then trigger BSOD on demand?

Comment: @MarianDolinský So the only difference between GSOD and BSOD is the Insider build? I think I'm running Insider preview on my Raspberry, does that change anything regarding triggering BSOD?

Comment: @Asunez Yeah, that should be the only difference. You can read more [here](https://www.theverge.com/2016/12/29/14111584/microsoft-windows-10-green-screen-of-death).

Comment: it depends on the services available that could be stopped.
i could always get a BSOD by killing the processes in the following order.

`RPCSS
LOCALSERVICE
NETWORKSERVICE
DLLHOST.exe 
NETSVCS `
it give 0xc000021a

Comment: @VGSandz I should've clarified this in my question - killing csrss.exe doesn't work because I have "Access denied" error. This occurs whenever I try to kill any system process. I will edit this into question.

Comment: I do not have an IoT Core install to test with but you might be able to trigger a BSoD with the PowerShell command `Get-Process | Stop-Process -Force` when running as an administrator.

Comment: @Persistent13 Please post this as an answer - it actually worked :) Using remote Power Shell I was able to trigger a BSOD on my IoT Device. I will mark this answer as accepted. The only thing I find strange is that I tried using the `-Force` parameter myself when trying to kill `csrss.exe`, and it refused - so I never actually tried killing any other processes as I thought the critical processes are somehow protected even against this parameter.

Comment: @Asunez Glad to hear it worked!

Comment: The only time my Win10 PC has BSODed I was trying figure out why my google drive on my PC wasn't syncing with the web version, and accidentally attempted to upload to the Google drive website a file from my local Google Drive folder instead of my desktop. I haven't attempted to recreate it because I don't just go around BSODing my personal device for funsies anymore, but maybe it would work consistently for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger a BSoD with the command `Get-Process | Stop-Process -Force`.